# How to parse a particular ids from a text file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, json

I have a lengthy text file, partial file content is shown below,

```
[{"site":"1a2v_1","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12807"},{"site":"1a2v_2","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12807"},{"site":"1a2v_3","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"T12807"},{"site":"1a2v_4","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12808"},{"site":"1a2v_5","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"Z12809"},{"site":"1a2v_6","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12821"},{"site":"1a3z_1","pfam":"Copper-bind,SoxE","uniprot":"P0C918"},
```

I need to parse `uniprot` ids from the above text file and the expected outcome is given below,

```
P12807
P12807
T12807
P12808
Z12809
P12821
P0C918
```

In order to do the same, I have tried the following commands but nothing works for me,

```
sed -e 's/"uniprot":"\(.*\)"},{"site":"/\1/' file.txt
cat file.txt | sed 's/.*"uniprot":" //' | sed 's/"site":".*$//'
```

Kindly help me to parse the ids as mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When dealing with structured data (like XML or JSON), it is best to use a dedicated parser like `xmlstarlet` or `jq` since they don't rely on a specific layout of the data.

Comment: I think you should accept the other answer instead of mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice carefully, your input file is a Python data structure. In particular, it is a list of dictionaries. We need to append a closing square bracket.

By means of the ast module we can serialize the string which is a valid Python data structure .

```
python3 -c 'import sys, ast
ifile,key = sys.argv[1:]
str = ""
with open(ifile) as fh:
  for l in fh: str += l.rstrip()
  lod = ast.literal_eval(str)
  for d in lod: print(d[key])
' file uniprot
```

---

```
P12807
P12807
T12807
P12808
Z12809
P12821
P0C918
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're on a Linux system, you can very easily do:

```
$ grep -oP '"uniprot":"\K[^"]+' file
P12807
P12807
T12807
P12808
Z12809
P12821
P0C918
```

The `-o` tells `grep` to only print the matching portion of each line and the `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. The regex is looking for `"uniprot":"` but then discards it (the `\K` means "discard anything matched so far", so that it isn't included in the output). Then, you just look for the longest stretch of non-`"` (`[^"]+`).

---

Of course, this looks like JSON data so for anything more complicated, you should use a proper parser for it like `jq`. If you fix your file by adding a closing `]` and make it like this:

```
[{"site":"1a2v_1","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12807"},{"site":"1a2v_2","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12807"},{"site":"1a2v_3","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"T12807"},{"site":"1a2v_4","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12808"},{"site":"1a2v_5","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"Z12809"},{"site":"1a2v_6","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12821"},{"site":"1a3z_1","pfam":"Copper-bind,SoxE","uniprot":"P0C918"}]
```

You can do:

```
$ jq -r '.[].uniprot' file
P12807
P12807
T12807
P12808
Z12809
P12821
P0C918
```

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OS system. Your command serve my purpose perfectly.  Thank you for your detailed explanation on the syntax. I got it.

Comment: I like you answer better - I didn't know about the perl extension for GNU grep! thanks

Comment: If any of the entries lack a `uniprot` key, you'd get `null` values. To skip these, use `.[].uniprot // empty`.

Comment: +1 for the jq answer, since that tool should be installed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for your example (with grep and sed):

```
grep -o '"uniprot":"[^"]*"' your_file | sed 's/.*:"\(.*\)"/\1/'
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- First we print `o`nly-matching parts of a grep search to get:

  ```
  "uniprot":"P12807"
  "uniprot":"P12807"
  "uniprot":"T12807"
  "uniprot":"P12808"
  "uniprot":"Z12809"
  "uniprot":"P12821"
  "uniprot":"P0C918"
  ```
- Then we pipe that to sed and use a capture group to remember the stuff in
  the last string, and replace each line with only that string to get:

  ```
  P12807
  P12807
  T12807
  P12808
  Z12809
  P12821
  P0C918
  ```

Comment: This would fail if the input data was change to be the equivalent but pretty printed JSON.

Comment: @Kusalananda this seems to work for pretty-printed JSON, but I don't have the general solution (pretty-printed/non-pretty-printed) yet: `cat file_test.txt | jq | grep -o '"uniprot": "[^"]*"' | sed 's/.*: "\(.*\)"/\1/'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `gawk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=","}
/uniprot/{print gensub(/.*("uniprot":")(.*)".*/, "\\2", "g") }' input
```

In this command, input Record Separator(`RS`) is set to comma.

Then `gawk` built-in function `gensub()` replaces line with desired pattern using backreferencing(`\\2`).

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -e 'slurp.comb( / <[{]>~<[}]> .+? / ).comb( / <["]>~<["]> .+? / ).map( *.subst: q["], :global ).[ 5, { $_ + 6 }...* ].join( Q:b[\n] ).put;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e '.put for slurp.comb( / <[{]>~<[}]> .+? / ).comb( / <["]>~<["]> .+? / ).map( *.subst: q["], :global ).[ 5, { $_ + 6 }...* ];'
```

Sample Input:

```
[{"site":"1a2v_1","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12807"},{"site":"1a2v_2","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12807"},{"site":"1a2v_3","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"T12807"},{"site":"1a2v_4","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12808"},{"site":"1a2v_5","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"Z12809"},{"site":"1a2v_6","pfam":"Cu_amine_oxid","uniprot":"P12821"},{"site":"1a3z_1","pfam":"Copper-bind,SoxE","uniprot":"P0C918"}]
```

Sample Output:

```
P12807
P12807
T12807
P12808
Z12809
P12821
P0C918
```

Briefly:

1. the file is slurped into Raku,
2. `comb` is used to select out curly-brace wrapped elements,
3. `comb` is again used to select out double-quoted elements,
4. in the selected elements, double-quotes are removed,
5. an index starting from 0 is generated taking every sixth element (i.e. the uniprot_ID), and
6. first example: uniprot_IDs are joined by `\n` and out`.put`.

I've tried to remove quoting characters as much as possible, to increase portability. Most importantly, the code above still works even if `jq` or `jq -r`, or `jq -c` are run on the input file, prior to feeding into Raku, e.g.:

```
cat uniprot_file.txt | jq -c | raku -e '...'
```

---

Addendum: It appears that Raku's `JSON::Tiny` module ***can*** parse a cleaned-up version of the OP's input file (with terminal characters corrected), but it requires a little extra work:

1. `list`-ifying the result of the `from-json()` call, and
2. `split`-ting on "`,` " comma-space to recover the hash objects.

```bash
~$ raku -MJSON::Tiny -e 'my @a = from-json($_).list given slurp;  \
         .<uniprot>.put for @a>>.split(", ");' uniprot_test.txt
P12807
P12807
T12807
P12808
Z12809
P12821
P0C918
```

https://forum.codeselfstudy.com/t/how-to-use-json-in-raku/2519
https://raku.org/

Comment: another option would be:
raku -ne '.say for .comb: /"\"uniprot\":\""<(\w+)>"\""/' file.txt

Comment: With better quotes:

raku -ne '.say for .comb: /\"uniprot\"\:\"<(\w+)>\"/' bla.json

Comment: Hi @SmokeMachine, thank you for the feedback! Your code definitely works on the input file given by the OP (@Kumar), cleaned up in the final few characters as per @terdon . However I was trying to anticipate problems noted in the comments above--e.g. if the ID file has been run through `jq` or not (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654337/how-to-parse-a-particular-ids-from-a-text-file/654467#comment1230046_654341). Running the input file through `jq` or `jq -r` prior to parsing with your one-liner(s) fails to return anything. That's why I opted for a longer (more general?) solution.

Comment: It seems `jq` would not work with that data, that's not a valid json. But here's another version that will work even if the input is well formatted:

raku -e '.say for slurp.comb: /\"uniprot\"<.ws>\:<.ws>\"<(\w+)>\"/' ble.json

Another option that would work for that "broken" data (I still need to work on its speed and make it easier to use) is using JSON::Stream like this:

raku -MJSON::Stream -e 'react whenever json-stream(@*ARGS.head.IO.words.Supply, [[q"$", *, "uniprot"],]) { .say }' bla.json

Comment: I like the JSON::Stream option because, even not being valid json, you can use json-path-like indexes to get it

Comment: With the new version of JSON::Stream (https://github.com/FCO/JSON-Stream), it became easier to set the JSON-path:
raku -MJSON::Stream -e 'react whenever json-stream "bla.json".IO.open.Supply, <$.*.uniprot> {.say }'

Comment: @SmokeMachine it would be great if you posted an alternative Perl5 and/or Raku solution. As I said earlier (and noted by at least a few other commenters), the OP put up a file-fragment that's pretty easily cleaned up. In such a case you WILL have better luck with a string search like words after `"uniprot\":\"`. But such searchs can fail if the search string is too common, like searching for `peptide` or `protein` or `enzyme`.

Comment: I'll definitely check out your JSON::Stream module (https://github.com/FCO/JSON-Stream), that looks like an answer you should post!

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. The files is not complete, it's probably valid JSON, even though I think the usage of JSON::Stream would be valid. The OP says its a big file, so, in that case JSON::Stream would not wait to parse the whole file to start returning data, it would emit the wanted data as soon as it was parsed, not having to wait the end of the whole file. :) sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Perl 5 solution

```
$ perl -nle 'print join"\n",m/uniprot\":\"(.*?)\"/g' file.txt
P12807
P12807
T12807
P12808
Z12809
P12821
P0C918
$
```